# When we have a new range for one field in ActiveRecord, can we change the validates code immediately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say, if we have

```
class SomeData < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :foo, inclusion: 33..99
```

and now, we say, we will make the range narrower, to `66..99`, but there are many values in the Database that are still between 33 and 65, can we change the above code to

```
class SomeData < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :foo, inclusion: 66..99
```

immediately?  Is it a problem if the data is just read into the system?  (even in earlier version of Rails such as 3.2?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a validation does not actually directly effect the existing data in your database in any way. Validations are only run when `#valid?` is called on the model.

This happens implicitly when you call:

- `.create` and `.create!`
- `#save` and `#save!`
- `#update` and `#update!`

And it causes these methods to bail so that either a rollback occurs or no db query is fired in the first place.

> Can we change the validation immediately?

Yes. The validation will only really kick in if you try to update an existing record. In which case a previously valid record may now be invalid. This will not permit an update unless the value is updated to be in the new permitted range.

### Dealing with legacy data

If you want to let users still update existing records with what is invalid data according to the new rules there are serveral tricks.

#### The `if:` and `unless:` options

```
class SomeData < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :foo, inclusion: 33..99, if: :legacy_record?
  validates :foo, inclusion: 66..99, unless: :legacy_record?
end
```

There are several ways to implement `:legacy_record?` like a boolean flag in the database. Note that these should not be confused with the ruby keywords. They are just hash options.

#### custom validation methods:

```
class SomeData < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :my_validation_method
  def my_validation_method
    rng = legacy_record? ? 33..99 : 66..99
    errors.add(:foo, "out of range") unless rng.cover?(foo)
  end
end
```

#### Single Table Inheritance

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :foo, inclusion: 66..99
end

class LegacyThing < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "things"
  validates :foo, inclusion: 33..99
end
```

In this example you would add a `things.type` varchar column and update the existing rows with `things.type = "LegacyThing"`. This isn't really STI - it just uses the mechanism built into ActiveRecord.

Comment: You can contrast this with a database constraint which would actually enforce this rule on the database level. The DB would not let you change the constraint if there are rows that would violate the new constraint.

Comment: aha... so I guess if the user reads in the data and alter the number, and we enforce it to be in the new range, then it will work.  I just talked to another coworker who said, in some situations, the user may alter the data, but for a different field (such as color), and we don't enforce that number to be in the new range, so I guess in this case, we can't change the `validates` for "legacy data range" reason

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was trying to get at. The new validation rules won't allow it. There are several workarounds for that though. You can create two different validations and use the `if:` and `unless:` options to to apply them to only new or legacy records or you can create two different model classes for the legacy and new records and add a `type` column to the table and use ActiveRecords built in STI mechanism.